# Monitor Start-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy in Azure powershell cmdlets

Tags: database, powershell, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to monitor an ongoing database copy, (Start-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy).
I've set up the following:

```
$dbCopy = Start-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy -ServerName $serverName -DatabaseName $sourceDbName -PartnerDatabase $targetDbName -PartnerServer $serverName

WHILE ($dbCopy)
{
   $dbCopy = Get-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy -ServerName $serverName -DatabaseCopy $dbCopy
   Write-Host $dbCopy.ReplicationStateDescription
   [System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep(1000);
}
```

The state is pending (the first approx. 7 times) and then returns an exception of "resource does not exist".
The database gets copied ok, but how do I monitor with script?'

This is where I got the general outline of the approach (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25268033/4261741)

Comment: Is that just what gets returned once the copy is finished? Or do you actually get a completed `ReplicationStateDescription` eventually?

Comment: In the while-loop, I get back a complete DataBaseCopy object with ReplicationStateDescription PENDING several times. It seems like when the status changes, I get this exception.

Comment: Yes but do you get the exception because it finished? If the copy has completed it seems reasonable that calling a `Get-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy` command might fail as the copy process doesn't exist any more

Comment: Yes, that's probably so. But I need to monitor when the jobs done without having try/catch handle an exception since I get the same exception if something is actually wrong.

Comment: So just add the try/catch around that single statement and examine the `message` property. If it's not `resource does not exist` then re-throw or handle some other way.

Comment: It seems like the only way, when dealing with azure. Since it's not a terminating error it's no biggy to handle it in a somewhat nice manner. Thanx for your input

Answer (score 1):

You can check the percentage as below.

```
Start-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy -ServerName $SourceServerName -DatabaseName $SourceDatabaseName -PartnerServer $TargetServerName -PartnerDatabase $TargetDatabaseName 

$i = 0

do
{
    sleep -Seconds 5
    $check = Get-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy -ServerName $TargetServerName -DatabaseName $TargetDatabaseName
    $i = $check.PercentComplete
}
while ($i -ne $null)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes back to this answer, if you use the new resource manager cmdlet, then you don't need to monitor progress. It blocks until the copy is complete. [New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603644.aspx).